# how to stop submit button while response thrown an error (php error)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My AJAX code is bellow

```
$("#step_3 :submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();


        var formData = $("#dbConfigID").serialize();

        $.ajax({

            url: "../pard_config/dbconfig.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            beforeSend:function(){

            },

            success: function(responce) {
            $("#res").show().html(responce);


            }

        });

    });
```

PHP CODE (only the catch )

```
 catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Warnning: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

if my database credentials  are wrong, it still show the 200 success code in the firebug.And my submit button is being triggering while php ajax response is an error like bellow

```
Warnning: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhosts' (1)
```

How to stop the button triggering while it was an error like above ?

Comment: The two actions/processes are completely separate. Once the AJAX request is sent, that part is over. You will get a 200 OK because the request was successful. On the other hand, if the PHP side generates an error while processing the request, there is no way to go back to JavaScript and prevent the original request. What you can do is on the PHP side echo an error if an error occurs and on the AJAX side, process the response you get i.e. success or error.

Comment: The problem is i have 4 steps ...while i pressing the #step_3 :submit button it will hide the step 2 and open the step 4 with success...if the php return an error the same thing have been return:( I mean my step 4 is being open.I want to stop that

Comment: You may want to do nothing on `success` then if you return a nicely formatted error. If the process fils you may want to add the `error` method for `$.ajax` to handle that case as well. For the submit issue, you can just return false or setup your submit button to call your function above and return false:

    `<button type="button" onclick="trySubmit(); return false;">Submit</button>`

Then on success, trigger the submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript cannot detect what happened on the server, so it goes off the HTTP status code. If you had a server-side failure, you need to return some kind of failure message to the client.

My personal preference is to leave the HTTP status codes alone, and send back a nice little json structure:

```
if ($failure) {
   echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failed', 'code' => xxx, 'message' => 'Something blew up!'));
}
```

then have

```
...
success: function(data) {
   if (data.status == 'failed') {
     throw ServerSideError;
   }
   ...
})
```

in your JS code.

Some will say you need to send an HTTP status code reflecting the error, which'd be

```
if ($failure) {
   header('HTTP/1.1 500 Database Error');
}
```

Javascript will pick up the non-2xx code and trigger the `error` code path in the AJAX handler.

Comment: Can't we use the ajax with error.what is that error settings with it ?

Comment: if the php thrown an error it will work with the ajax error settings ?

Comment: php throws will NOT trigger a JS catch. remember. php executes on the server, javascript executes on the client. php needs to send a failure message to JS.

Comment: The problem is i have 4 steps ...while i pressing the #step_3 :submit button it will hide the step 2 and open the step 4 with success...if the php return an error the same thing have been return:( I mean my step 4 is being open.I want to stop that

Comment: yes, and? so your step #3 submission logic needs to check the response from the server for errors, and NOT move on to step 4 if there was a problem.

Comment: var OnSuccess = $("#res").text();
    
    if (onSuccess === "connected"){
    
    $("#step_3").hide();
    $("#step_4").show();
    
    }

Comment: i's echo a connected word the php page and if it on the response are i'll going to hide the step 3 and open the step 4 .this is not working